# How to remove elements from Set by iterator with specific conditions?

Tags: java, iterator, set

For the moment, I have this code. Obviously, it's impossible to compare iterator with 10, but how can I get value of current iterator element? Or I should use something different?

```
public static Set<Integer> removeAllNumbersGreaterThan10(Set<Integer> set) {
        Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it > 10) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
```

Comment: How would you normally use an `Iterator`? Hint: your code currently doesn't iterate.

Comment: Integer i; while (it.hasNext()) {i = it.next() ...

Comment: You have to call `next()` to check the next element, then call `remove()` if the condition matches. But easier to use `set.removeIf(i -> i > 10);`.

Comment: Simpler than this `set.removeIf(val -> val > 10);
        return set;`

Comment: Thank you all, my fault, lost in "next" words, thought it must be "current".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
if( it.next() >10){
  it.remove()
}
```

Comment: I thought concurrent modification occurs in for loops and only to avoid that we use iterators !!!

Comment: Try it and see. Concurrent modification occurs when you modify a `Collection` during iteration.

Comment: Thanks! Just got lost in this "next" word, thought it should be current.